How to change color of Text in Google Charts?

Unfortunately, I don't know what this text is called (circled).
hAxis: { textStyle: { color: '#eff1f4' }},
vAxis: { textStyle: { color: '#eff1f4' }}

and
 titleTextStyle: { color: '#eff1f4'}

They seem to not work. What is the solution?

you're looking for --> legend.textStyle
legend: { textStyle: { color: '#eff1f4' }}

